# Copy the result of an effect on one layer to a new layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, cs6

I have a rectangular shape that has a colour overlay and drop shadow in a layer. Now, I want to create a new layer containing only a rasterized version of the effect from the current layer.

To put it simply:

Layer 1: Shape + shape-drop-shadow;
(Create new Layer 2)
Layer 2: shape-drop-shadow;

Meaning, I'm not looking for how to copy effects between layers, but rather the actual result of the effect of one layer to a new layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Select the layer you want to copy.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to duplicate it.
3. Right-click the new layer and select *Rasterize Layer Style*.
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ click the shape icon in the new layer in the layer palette to select it and press <kbd>DELETE</kbd> to keep just the effect.

**EDIT**: Missed the part about the color overlay, my answer works for the drop shadow and other effects outside of the shape.

Comment: Awesome answer! I found another way also, which was to set the fill of the shape to 0%, duplicate the layer and rasterize the layer. Then I got a rasterized copy of the shape shadow. This approach felt smoother though! Btw, the overlay was never really a problem, it was the shadow I was after. So thanks!

Comment: I followed your method and it deletes the entire newly copied layer.

Comment: @KeepMove Did you press control and click the shape in the layer palette before pressing delete?

Comment: @Olle Sjögren I did. May be I missed a thing too. But that's not a problem anymore. I found a way on the newer version of Photoshop (please see my answer down there).

Comment: im lost at step 4.. Can you show me what the  shape icon looks like?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Just CTRL+click the image of the Shape layer in the layers panel (example: https://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/basics/cs6/layers/layers-panel/photoshop-layer-transparency.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you *did* need the effects of the colour overlay / blend modes as well as layer styles, which can get lost in Rasterize Layer Style, there's a simple workaround I quite often use:

- [Hide every other layer](https://superuser.com/questions/346879/how-to-hide-all-layer-except-one-in-photoshop-cs5-5) (alt-click the eye symbol)
- Select > All (`ctrl+A`)
- Edit > Copy Merged (`ctrl+shift+C`) which copies the output of all visible layers as one (you must be in any layer that's visible, or it doesn't work)
- Paste

It pastes a new layer containing the final pixel output of whatever was going on in the unhidden layer(s) - including transparency, blending, and layer styles. Then overlay / blend modes etc can be applied to that layer to make it play nicely with everything else.

Comment: +1 for providing an additional solution when requesting a different result!

Answer (score 0):

This has been many years late, but I posted this answer just in case other people need it.

This method was tested with `Inner Shadow` effect of Blending Options in Photoshop CC 2015.

1. Select the layer (which is have effect) on the layer palette. Do not Rasterize it.
2. Decrease the `Fill` scroll slider to 0%. It is the slider under the `Opacity` slider.

You are now get the effect with transparent background.

Answer (score -2):

First copy old layer and paste to new document 
second copy old layer style and paste to new document !